# Unable to understand the syntax of this statemnet "struct sll_header *shdr = (struct sll_header *)buf;"

Tags: c, pointers, character, structure

Below is the code snippet I was trying to read through.

```
swap_linux_sll_header(const struct pcap_pkthdr *hdr, u_char *buf)
{
    u_int caplen = hdr->caplen;
    u_int length = hdr->len;
    struct sll_header *shdr = (struct sll_header *)buf;
    uint16_t protocol;
    pcap_can_socketcan_hdr *chdr;

    if (caplen < (u_int) sizeof(struct sll_header) ||
        length < (u_int) sizeof(struct sll_header)) {
        /* Not enough data to have the protocol field */
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like C code.  Could be C++, but it isn't idiomatic C++.

Comment: this is just a type cast.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple type cast. buf is originally passed to the function as a pointer to u_char, but inside the function it needs to be used and examined/manipulated as a pointer to a sll_header structure.

This is common when a buffer is obtained as a raw sequence of bytes, perhaps it's  read off a medium or a network and then it's passed to a function that understands the underlying structure it represents (e.g. an IP packet) and makes sense of it.

Without the type case, you will get a compiler warning.